# unplug the external monitor(hdmi), the launcher and top menu bar are hidden

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors, launcher, hdmi

I ask the question on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42714999/unplug-the-external-monitorhdmi-the-launcher-and-top-menu-bar-are-hidden

```
I do not have enough reputations to post image :(
```

I google it many times, but the answers are always about the hdmi, mulitple monitor, they are not my problem -- about the Unity

the problem is ,

when I unplug the external monitor (HDMI), the launcher and top menu bar are hidden /disappeared, I can see the desktop background (like the second picture).

and when the mouser click the hidden area, the bars appears(like the first picture).

and when I logout, and login the unity session, the bars are back to work (like the first picture).

the following is the OS info

```
cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS \n \l
uname -a
Linux trydofor-5510 4.4.0-66-generic 
#87-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 3 15:29:05 UTC 2017 
x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```